# ruby script for jabber nagios alerts

Tags: nagios, ruby, xmpp

I'm looking for a ruby script for have nagios jabber alerts.

Someone knows some script or api ?

thanks

Comment: why does it have to be ruby? I have used this in the past: http://www.gridpp.ac.uk/wiki/Nagios_jabber_notification, it's Perl but it could give you some ideas if you want to rewrite it ruby if you are really bored ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at RI Pienaar's angelia projet: https://github.com/ripienaar/angelia

It supports XMPP notifications from nagios and is written in Ruby.